# How to use NMR readings to determine the molecular structure of a compound?

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure, nmr-spectroscopy, chemical-formula

A question in my exam came as follows:

> How is NMR used in the determination of structure of organic compounds?

I have studied NMR spectroscopy and I know how to determine values using an NMR spectroscope. However, none of my textbooks talk about how to actually use these readings to determine the actual molecular structure of the compound that is under study. My professor has not taught this either. I was unable to find any external sources that talk about this as well.

Could someone explain the steps on how to determine the molecular structure of a compound after knowing the spectrum?

Comment: Then you should already know all you need about that.

Comment: I’m closing this question because Stack Exchange isn't an essay-writing service.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113189/discussion-between-m-farooq-and-naved-the-sheikh).

Comment: In addition to @M.Farooq 's advice, my recommendation is to flip the problem on its head and use your intuition. If you know what parameters can be measured by NMR and their origin, then think about how those parameters might be used to determine (intuit) structure. For instance, shifts depend on and therefore give you information about the local chemical environment, including bonding, vicinity of substituents, etc. J-couplings (including peak multiplicity) depend on and therefore give you information about connectivity (bonding networks).

Comment: Browsing this site and looking up NMR questions and answers might help give you an idea of how nmr is used. Your question as it stands is a little broad. There isn't just "the spectrum", there is a slew of possible experiments that can be performed depending on the complexity of the molecule.